# Getting min and max

Tags: javascript

Write a program that accesses the Employee Payroll Records Set. The program will determine the average, maximum, and minimum Hourly Wage for the employees. Output the result formatted as shown in the sample output.

Write this program using functions to divide the program up into modules. The main function should consist of mostly function calls, plus a WHILE loop. In this case, several of the IF statements within the main function are so simple that they are just handled entirely within the main function.

**Max should equal 30**
**Min should equal 0**

**I can't get it to display those results.**
**Those numbers can not be hard coded, have to be determined by opening the record.**

Here is my code:

```
const START_VALUE = 0;
var records;
var counter;
var hourlyWage;
var grandSumHourlyWages;
var minimumHourlyWage;
var averageHourlyWage;
var maximumHourlyWage;


function assignInitialValuesToVariables() {
"use strict";

counter = START_VALUE;
hourlyWage = START_VALUE;
grandSumHourlyWages = START_VALUE;
averageHourlyWage = START_VALUE;
minimumHourlyWage = START_VALUE;
maximumHourlyWage = START_VALUE;
}

// purpose of this function is to calculate the average
function calculateAverageHourlyWage() {
averageHourlyWage = grandSumHourlyWages / counter;
}

// purpose of this function is to display the results
function displayMinimumMaximumAverageHourlyWage() {
    document.write("Average Hourly Wage: " + averageHourlyWage + "<br/>"
    + "Maximum Hourly Wage: " + maximumHourlyWage + "<br/>"
    + "Minumum Hourly Wage: " + minimumHourlyWage);
}

function lab12puttingItAllTogetherPart2() {
"use strict";

// A suggested main function for Part 2 is below:

assignInitialValuesToVariables();

records = openEmployeePayrollRecords();          // pre-existing function

while ( records.readNextRecord() ) {
    hourlyWage = records.getEmployeeHourlyWage();   //pre-existing method
    grandSumHourlyWages += hourlyWage;    // for later use in calc avg wage
    counter++;

    if (hourlyWage < minimumHourlyWage) {
        minimumHourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    }


    // here write the IF to handle max hourly wage
    if (hourlyWage > maximumHourlyWage) {
        maximumHourlyWage = hourlyWage;
    }

}

calculateAverageHourlyWage();

displayMinimumMaximumAverageHourlyWage();
```

}

Comment: What does `openEmployeePayrollRecords()` return?

Comment: It doesn't return anything. It opens a different file that contains the records of employee payroll.